# Mounting the hard drive when booting from a cd

Tags: boot, mount, hard-drive

Is it possible to mount the hard drive when booting from a cd ? If so, how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are booting from Ubuntu 12.04 CD, open nautilus (the folder icon on the launcher at the left edge of the screen). On the left panel of nautilus you should see your hard drive partitions. Click on the one you want to mount. It should open in the right panel of nautilus.